# Open source mobile GIS data inspection software

Tags: android, open-source, gis, geo-location

In my workplace we are looking at collecting and inspecting GIS data using free mobile apps. The one that is fit-for-purpose from a data collection point of view is GeoODK. I have been able to prepare custom forms and get them to work in the field really well.

We already have GIS data in a proprietary GIS file format (shp, tab etc.) *but can export to other formats if required* and we would like to inspect them on a mobile app.

Ideally, I would like to have this loaded onto an app as a form and then have the inspections done by changing a few fields such as 'Inspection date', 'Inspection Officer' etc. and then capture new data along the way if these did not exist in the original GIS file.

Can anyone recommend any open source GIS software for the same?

Comment: Android, iOS or WinMobile? Which proprietary format for the existing GIS data?

Comment: Hello @SteveBarnes- Looking for something on an Android device. Existing GIS data could be exported in any format, we are pretty flexible in that regard (SHP, TAB, GeoJSON).

Comment: VGu - added both into question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might like to take a look at [QField](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.opengis.qfield&hl=en_GB):

- Open Source (GPL v2)
- Data Preparation in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/)
- Attach photo to coordinates, etc.
- Add your own data fields & forms, form creation, etc. also in QGIS

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion with this one Steve. However, it appears very clunky on my android device. Is this something that is device/android version specific? I could not really add features when I chose the digitize option. Instead, it only allowed me to delete features. Any advice on this regard? Thank you once again.

Comment: @VGu I suspect that there will be differences in how the display looks on different devices & Android Versions. As with any open source project you can always raise tickets on missing features and raise pull requests to add them & most developers welcome, _polite_, bug reports. See https://github.com/opengisch/QField for the repository.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link here to extent this discussion to the new versrion of QField and also a product called 'Input'.

https://www.geoawesomeness.com/best-field-data-collection-mobile-app-qgis/